# converting code from using await fetch to using import

Tags: reactjs, import, async-await, fetch

I have the following code block in the project I inherited:

```
const fetchAvailableDates = React.useCallback(
    () => {
        const fetchAvailableDates = async () => {
            try {
               const dates = await fetch ( 'https://S3 URL/myproject/mypath/index.json',
               {credentials : 'include'} ).then (res => res.json());
               // Other code partially listed below
               dispatch ({ type: 'SET_AVAILABLE_DATES', dates });
```

The group which wants to have me modify this code doesn't want to use S3 storage any longer and so I'm trying to read their data from local files using **import**.  I modified the **bolded** line to read:

const dates = import('../mylocalpath/mylocalfiles/index.json');

but that causes a downstream error in code that references the *dates* variable.

How can I modify this code so that I can use **import** instead of **await fetch**.  I am **NOT** a Javascript programmer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is it that you exactly want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to de-couple the application from using S3 storage and instead have it read from local files.

Comment: so data would be static?

Comment: yes, it would generated by the same external process but instead of putting the data in S3, the output would go to a directory local to the React.js app.  There are  2 files now that are being read that way but they are not wrapped in an async/callback code block.